# Why not have an array with a negative number as index?

Tags: c#

C# arrays, why not have an array with a negative number as index? This situation is sometimes very useful; especially for a fast algorithm in some special type of sorting. Two questions: 1) Why not?
2) Any efficient workaround?

Comment: You can use a `Dictionary` to map from a negative number to something else.

Comment: You can create a class deriving from linked list and overload the [] operator to feel as you are using an array.

Comment: Do you mean that -1 should return the last element in the array?

Comment: @TomF [_The array indexing operator cannot be overloaded, but you can define indexers._](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8edha89s.aspx)

Comment: Please define what that you mean. Is ProgramFOX correct, or do you want indices to start not from zero but from some (presumably user-supplied) other number, which might be negative? Or is it something else entirely?

Comment: Wow C# disappointed me just now @SonerGönül

Comment: @user1191177 Never just say stuff like that without an explanation.

Comment: My question as to why indices of an array cannot be normally a negative number, has been put on hold as off-topic. Wish at least some explanation should have been allowed first.

Answer (score 3):

You can always implement your own class with an [indexer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/6x16t2tx.aspx). For example:

```
public class MyClass {
    public String this[int index] {
        get {
            // ... 
        }

        set {
            // ... 
        }
    }
}
```

where `String` is the return type as an example.

Answer (score 2):

In some languages arrays start at zero, because the underlying offset into the data structure to the item starts at zero. That is the simplest implementation, and it leaves it up to the programmer to use it the best way.

Some languages allow other base indexes, but then there is an additional cost to calculate the offset from the index. What you gain in simpler code, you lose in a more complex implementation of arrays.

The most efficient workaround would be to adjust the index yourself when you access the array. There are other solutions that give cleaner code, but they are not as efficient. You can for example wrap the array in a class and provide an indexer that adjusts the index, which gives a seamless implementation with a reasonable amount of overhead.

Answer (score 2):

You can create your own class which will wrap a array and provide index translation when accessing it. You would want to write something like that:

```
public class ArrayWithAnyIndexes<ArrayType>
{

  private ArrayType[] arrayToWrap;
  private int firstIndex;

  public ArrayWithAnyIndexes(ArrayType[] arrayToWrap, int firstIndex)
  {
    this.arrayToWrap = arrayToWrap;
    this.firstIndex = firstIndex;
  }

   public ArrayTypethis[int index] {
        public get {
            return this.arrayToWrap[index - firstIndex]; 
        }

        public set {
            this.arrayToWrap[index - firstIndex] = value;
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

The [`Array.CreateInstance` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x836773a.aspx) *could* in theory be used to create arrays with a non-zero lower bound:

```
Array.CreateInstance(
    elementType: typeof(T), 
    lengths: new int[] { length }, 
    lowerBounds: new int[] { lowerBound });
```

The only trouble is that C# won't allow you to cast the returned array to `T[]`; that would only be permissible, and work, for multi-dimensional arrays (`T[,]` etc.).

This is likely in some way due to the fact that the CLR treats one-dimensional arrays with a lower bound of zero specially; these are called "vectors" and get some special optimizations that neither multi-dimensional arrays nor ones with non-zero lower bounds will receive.

But in all truth, I don't know for sure why *exactly* C# restricts one-dimensional arrays to vectors.

Comment: Interresting, but when I try to call it, I get `System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.String[*]' to type 'System.String[]'.`.

Comment: @Guffa: Oh boy… you're right. I just checked with my copy of "CLR via C#". That conversion is not possible for one-dimensional arrays. Which makes my answer useless, but I'll leave it out there in a corrected state.

Comment: You can cast the `T[*]` array you created in the answer to the **non-generic** version of the `IList` interface. Then you can access it like `T read = (T)arr[-12];` and `arr[-12] = write;`. Unfortunately you cannot use the generic `IList<T>` interface with a `T[*]` array; that only works with `T[]`.